# Корректно ли я использую try except?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram

Я делаю небольшого телеграмм бота на aiogramm:

```
if message.text.lower() == 'магазин страховок':
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        #code
        data['magazine'] = True
async with state.proxy() as data:
    try:
        if message.text.lower() == 'страховка на жизнь' and data['magazine']:
            #code
            data['magazine'] = False
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

В данном коде пользователь вводить "Магазин страховок" и ему предлагают купить страховку, он выбирает нужную и все работает, но если не заходить в "Магазин страховок" и вписать допустим "Страховка на жизнь" мне выбивает ошибку о том что я не инициализирую переменную, ошибка мне не мешает, все так и должно быть, я хочу узнать корректно ли я выкрутился с ситуации или нет? (Я не могу инициализировать переменную ибо работаю в одном обработчике событий и переменная постоянно будет меняться)

Comment: Не проще объявить переменную и дать ей значение false. В самом начале? Тогда и try не нужен будет вовсе.

Comment: В этом и проблема, я пишу на aiogramm в одном обработчике событий, когда пользователь будет что либо вводить значение переменной будет выставляться как False постоянно

Answer (score 0):

Выкрутиться-то вы выкрутились... А смысл?

```
if message.text.lower() == 'магазин страховок':
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        #code
        data['magazine'] = True
async with state.proxy() as data:
    try:
     # Переменная data['magazine'] не определена... и всегда проверка условия будет 
     # приводить к пропуску try, и переходу к except...
     # Поэтому весь этот фрагмент кода можно заменить одним pass
        if message.text.lower() == 'страховка на жизнь' and data['magazine']:
            #code
            data['magazine'] = False
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Если вы хотите установить False из-за не верно выбранной строки (мое предположение), тогда:

```
if message.text.lower() == 'магазин страховок':
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        #code
        data['magazine'] = True
else:
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        #code
        data['magazine'] = False
```

Ну а если вы хотите проверить состояние переменной...

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    try:
        if data['magazine']:
            #code
            #вот тут пишем, что делать если data['magazine'] установлена.
            pass
    except KeyError:
        #code
        #вот тут пишем, что делать если data['magazine'] не установлена.
        pass
    
    #необезательный 
    else:
        #code
        #выполнится в случае если исключений не было
        pass
    #необязательный
    finally:
        #code
        #выполнится в любом случае
        pass
```

[Официальная справочка](https://docs.python.org/release/3.6.15/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=exceptions)

Comment: Второй код это почти аналог того если бы я присваивал переменную до инициализации переменной, потому что если у меня будет стоять переменная со значением "True" и пользователь введет "Страховка на жизнь"  то в коде `if message.text.lower() == 'магазин страховок':` У меня присвоиться False и блок с "Страховка на жизнь" не выполниться.
И на счет моего кода, мне не нужно что бы блок с "Страховка на жизнь" выполнялся если пользователь не ввел "магазин страховок"

Comment: А что мешает проверить переменную на False, и в этом случае пустить блок "Страховка на жизнь"?

Comment: У меня будет не инициализированная переменная, если же я буду делать это после присваивания значения переменной, тогда у меня на выходе будет постоянно False

Comment: То есть вам нужно третье значение... используйте None. Не инициализированная переменная - плохо...